# How to redirect in Flask inside function

Tags: python, flask, download, youtube

I am working on a Flask site, and in that

A video starts downloading, and when download completes, it should call a function which then will redirect the user to another page.

the `.download_complete(function)` runs when the video is successfully downloaded, and this runs a function with args details and file path

```
def redirectTheUser(details, filepath):
   -Some code that should redirect user-


@app.route("/download")
def download():
    -some code -
    yt.download_complete(redirectTheUser)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to find out what can I do:

So what I am doing now is redirecting but using Javascript, if the download complete variable (using jinja vars) is true

Py file

```
downloadStatus = False
#By default download status will be False

def redirectUser(self, filepath):
    global downloadStatus
    downloadStatus = True


@app.route("/download")
def download():
    yt.download_complete(redirectUser)
    global downloadStatus
    return render_template("download.html", downloadStatus = downloadStatus)
```

download.html file

```
<HTML>
........

<body>
....

<script>

downloadComplete = "{{ downloadStatus }}"
if (downloadComplete == "True"){
    window.location.replace("--redirevt your user--")
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```